# Does this syntax for zero-argument functions work in R?

Tags: r

I have a function `f` which takes no arguments and returns a data frame with a bunch of variables `x1, x2, ... xi`. Later I will want to pull out one of those `xi`. So, is this syntax viable?

```
aColumn <- f()$xi
```

Or do I have to do this:

```
allX <- f()
aColumn <- allX$xi
```

`f` is a complicated function, which itself is part of a very complicated Shiny app, so the answer to this question will help me isolate the error I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the details of your function it is difficult to answer this question with certainty. But I don't think that there is any categorical reason why it would not work.

Here is a (presumably) similar example:

```
set.seed(123)
nums <- sample(5, 20, replace = TRUE)
myfun <- function(x = nums) rle(x)
myfun()$lengths
#[1] 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

This result is identical to

```
temp <- myfun()
temp$lengths
#[1] 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Therefore, as far as I can tell from the information provided in the OP, I would assume that the syntax `f()$xi` is correct.